# Send value to child component in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a component that takes a parameter that can be true or false, I put it in the console to check.

```
console.log(isContract);
//can be true ou false
```

I need to send this value through a form that will render another component.

This is the parent component:

```
return (
    <Contract
      savingsFactors={formValues.savingsFactors}
      onFieldSubmit={...}
    />
)
```

And here in the internal component, if my value that came from the other component is true, I need to change the items

```
const Contract = ({ savingsFactors }) => (
      <PutField
        label={label}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onBlur={...}

        // if isContract === true, return this:
        items={savingsFactors === 'true' ? FORM_VALUES : FORM_VALUES_NORMAL}

        // if isContract === false, return this:
        items={savingsFactors === 'true' ? ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES : ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES_NORMAL}
      />
);
```

**What is the simplest way to send the isContract to the internal component and load the items according to the result?**

I'm studying react and I'm having a lot of trouble with it, thanks a lot to those who help

Comment: Why are you not passing it to the Contact component just like the other properties?

Comment: hmmm, nice! And how do I do the if inside the other form to load the correct item?

Comment: Properties (props) are a fundamental aspect of React. Virtually any tutorial is going to mention them early on. Take your pick. I don't feel the need to rehash that information here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with defined props in React, but If I remember correctly, this should go something like this:

**Edit 1**
Added a render method inside the Contract component.

**Edit 2**
I just realized that you have a component inside your contract component XD which should be inside the render method itself. I think that might be the issue.

```js
return (
    <Contract
      savingsFactors={formValues.savingsFactors}
      isContract={isContract}
      onFieldSubmit={...}
    />
)
```

And your component should be something like (**After Edit 2**):

```js
const Contract = (props) => (  
  render(){
    let items = [];

    if (props.isContract === true)
    {
      items={props.savingsFactors === 'true' ? FORM_VALUES : FORM_VALUES_NORMAL}
    }

    //BTW, should this be !== true? :P
    if (props.isContract === true)
    {
      items={props.savingsFactors === 'true' ? ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES : ANOTHER_FORM_VALUES_NORMAL}
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>I have {items.length} items... or something...<h2>

        <PutField
          label={label}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          **items={items}** /*Maybe?*/
          onBlur={...}
        />

      </div>
    )
  }      
);
```

Comment: This is generally correct, but modern React doesn't use `props.`.

Comment: Thanks @LeoSanchez!!. But I can't use the IF inside PutField, maybe I should create a component for that?

Comment: That's an odd statement. You should revise your question to explain better.

Comment: Do you have a working component? At the end of the day, your component should have a render method, I'm certain you can have your if statements inside of it. Which version of react are you using?